# Need to change the background image random with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello all this is my code til now , i need to change #mainImage background with 5 background-`images(img-1.jpg, img-2.jpg , img-3.jpg ,img-4.jpg ,img-5.jpg )` , the background will Change random with jquery (.css), when i reload page .

Thanks

Comment: Where are you stuck? No try on your side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var images = ['img-1.jpg', 'img-2.jpg', 'img-3.jpg', 'img-4.jpg', 'img-5.jpg']; 
var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
$('#mainImage').css('background', 'url(' + images[random] + ')');
```

Answer (score 2):

Or more generic approach

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var images = [
        'img-1.jpg',
        'img-2.jpg',
        'img-3.jpg',
        'img-4.jpg',
        'img-5.jpg'
    ];

    var key = Math.floor((Math.random()*images.length));
    var img = images[ key ];
    $('#mainImage').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')' );
});
```